# Measurement units style typesetting guidelines for scientific writing

Tags: math-mode, typography

When I write scientific content that uses measurement units I usually refers to the following guidelines for the typesetting:

- [NIST](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/checklist.html)
- [UK Metric System](http://ukma.org.uk/docs/ukma-style-guide.pdf)
- [BIPM](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/)

Summarizing:

- There should be a space between the numeric value and the measurements unit
- No Italic, the symbols for units and SI prefixes are roman
- A dot is sometimes used to separate the units symbols multiplied

But I am not sure what is the best way to transform these guidelines into LaTeX code. 
So far I've been using a code like this:

```
3.98~\mathrm{m \cdot kg \cdot s^{-3} \cdot A^{-1}}
```

That leads to:

[image]

Is this the best way to express unit measurements in publications?

Comment: Read `siunitx` documentation. It's pretty flexible. If you want the dot, just add `\sisetup{inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to typeset (SI-)units is the [`siunitx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) by Joseph Wright. It is very elaborate and lets you customize the behaviour of the display command `\SI{value}{unit}` – please read the documentation…there are way to many features in this awesome package to explain everything in full detail in one post.

Your example would 'translate' to

```
\SI{2.98}{\meter\kilogram\per\cubic\second\per\ampere}
```

Simple and beautiful…

Comment: Thanks however actually this package do not use the dot notation that is supposed to be used referring to NIST guidelines.

Comment: @GM You can configure it to do so, see section 5.12 of the manual. And NIST says "A space **or** half-high dot is used to signify the multiplication of units". (emphasis mine)

Comment: What do you mean by 'dot notation'? The \cdot command you used to seperate the units? Of cours siunitx does support that! Just use \si[inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}]
{3.98}{\meter\kilogram\per\cubic\second\per\ampere} or set the option globally

Comment: @FabianA. `\SI[<options>]{<value>}{<unit>}`. The lowercase version (`\si[<options>]{<unit>}`) is for typesetting only a unit, without a value.

Comment: Yeah right…I didn't try the commands, just typed what I remembered. My bad!

Comment: @GM the [offical SI guide](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/) also doesn't use a dot (and IIRC was the source material for many of the defaults implemented in `siunitx`)

Comment: @ChrisH Okay I have updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: Note the unit is called 'metre' not 'meter': the latter is allowed by the package

Comment: @JosephWright are you sure of what are you talking about? Are you familiar with the package? ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright I'm german (my excuse for everything…) so 'meter' is the natural spelling for me.

Comment: The BIPM says "small spelling variations occur in the language of the English speaking countries (for instance, 'metre' and 'meter', 'litre' and 'liter')." The NIST uses "meter".